# Error: Cannot extend type "Query" because it is not defined

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am getting this error while extending Query in GraphQL schema. Here is error stack:

```
stack=[Error: Cannot extend type "Query" because it is not defined.,     at assertValidSDL (/NodeGraphQL/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:108:11),     
at Object.buildASTSchema (/NodeGraphQL/node_modules/graphql/utilities/buildASTSchema.js:71:34),     
at Object.buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions (/NodeGraphQL/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/generate/buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions.js:23:28),     
at Object.makeExecutableSchema (/NodeGraphQL/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/makeExecutableSchema.js:26:29),     
at ApolloServer.initSchema (/NodeGraphQL/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/ApolloServer.js:272:49),     
at new ApolloServerBase (/NodeGraphQL/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/ApolloServer.js:202:30),     
at new ApolloServer (/NodeGraphQL/node_modules/apollo-server-express/dist/ApolloServer.js:59:9),     
at Object.<anonymous> (/NodeGraphQL/dist/server.js:17:16),     
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30),     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10),     
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32),     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12),     
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3),     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12),     
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19),     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)]
```

Here is how my schema looks like:

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express';

export const ticket = gql`
  type Ticket {
    id: ID!
    subject: String
    priority_id: Int
    status_id: Int
    user_id: Int
    assigned_to_user_id: Int
  }

  extend type Query {
    tickets: [Ticket]
    ticket(id: ID!): Ticket
  }
`;
```

Looking for the solution :)

Comment: Can you provide more information or repo for this example so we can have a better look?

Comment: @parth thats all what I have.

Comment: Maybe this can help. https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1158

Comment: Ok Thanks @parth

Comment: Check this thread, https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/922, might help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `extend` keyword is used to augment an existing type within the same schema. For example, we can do:

```
type User {
  username: String!
}

extend type User {
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
}
```

This is useful when splitting your schema across multiple files or building your schema from a base schema.

You cannot, however, extend a type that doesn't exist. You have no defined a `Query` type in your schema, so you cannot extend it. Just remove the `extend` keyword.

Comment: I am referring (https://blog.logrocket.com/from-rest-to-graphql/) in which they have used extend keyword. I don't know what is the use of this

Comment: @rahul Please see my edit for an additional explanation. I'm not sure why the tutorial you're referencing uses the extend keyword -- if you're using `graphql-modules`, you actually don't need it because of how that library works under the hood. But with `graphql-modules`, it should work either way. If you're *not* using that library, you should only use extend if the type already exists.

Comment: I would suggest referencing the actual documentation for both `apollo-server` and `graphql-modules` rather than relying exclusively on a tutorial. You'll get better examples and a better explanation of why you're doing things a certain way.

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel, I am using apollo-server-express modules to build GraphQL server.